# Regex for Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to learn some basic Javascript regex.  As starters, I read the documentation and this SO question:
[How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

I think I've deciphered most of the expression:

```
/(?:^|\s)format_(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g
```

Except this part:

```
(.*?)
```

I know that

```
.*
```

is to match 0 or more occurrences of any character (except newline or line terminator).

But I can't figure out why the

```
?
```

is needed.

I was playing with something similar:

```
/(?:^|\s)ab(.*?)ab(?:\s|$)/
' ab4545ab '
```

And things have been behaving the same with or without the

```
?
```

in

```
(.*?)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: The question mark in that context means to do a `lazy` match.

Comment: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Comment: do read this - great tutorial, useful examples and all to the point: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html, and this in particular http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

Comment: @Joanna: Thanks for those links.  They helped a lot.  I was still confused after reading the answers (but of course they all would have pointed me in the right direction), but after reading your link, they all made sense.  I wish you had posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes the `.*` non-greedy. This means that the first occurrence of the next valid character sequence in the regex will halt the `.*`.

Without the `?`, the `.*` will consume until the last occurrence of the next valid character sequence in the regex.

```
var s = "foo bar boo bar foo";

var greedy = /.*bar/;
var no_greed = /.*?bar/;

greedy.exec(s); // foo bar boo bar

no_greed.exec(s); // foo bar
```

So the greedy one consumes past the first "bar" to the last "bar".

The non-greedy only goes to the first "bar".

Answer (score 4):

The `?` after a `.+` or `.*` match will make the match **lazy** instead of the default **greedy**. Meaning, it will match as few characters as possible, in contrast to as many.

Example:

```
"hello".match(/.+/)    //Returns ["hello"]
"hello".match(/.+?/)   //Returns ["h"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `?` makes the quantifier ungreedy. Without it, the `*` will eat up as many characters as possible, which is particularly powerful with `.`. However, with the `?` there, it will eat as few as necessary.

Take this string, for example: `"abcccbacba"`, and match it against `/abc(.*)ba/`. It will result in capturing `ccbac`. On the other hand, `/abc(.*?)ba/` will capture `cc`.